# I cannot pubish link on facebook from my facebook app

Tags: facebook

I'm trying Facebook Graph API Explorer in order to publish link in my wall.
I use this link
https:/graph.facebook.com/myfacebookid/links
The fields are
message = test
link = http://www.stefanoerrani.it/

If I use Graph API Explorer as application the link is published in my wall and on wall of my friends.
If I use my Facebook web application the link is published only on my wall.
I have setted: pubish stream, status_update, read_stream in both applications and accepted them when I generate the access token.

Why in my application I cannot publish link also in my friends wall?

Comment: Are you trying to post directly to friend's feed OR you publishing it on user's feed and want it to appear in his friends feeds too?

Comment: I publish the post on only on my wall and I should want that it appears automatically on my friend's walls same as I write it manually.

Answer (score 0):

That is odd behavior.  I'm sure it has to do with a filter Facebook has in place that determines what is cross-posted to friends feed when something is posted to your feed.  Maybe Facebook sees the API Explorer higher in it's ranking and auto-cross posts it there while your app is still fledgling and doesn't have a high enough ranking/weight.

Comment: There is a way to know waht you said?
And how can I do to verify if my app is properly setted?

Comment: Ranking is done by Facebook's algorithms.  I can make a SWAG that they base it on the number of people who don't remove or mark your app's postings/requests/notifications in a bad way.

Comment: Really my application is used only for publish the posts from my web site.
The only way to use it is within my web site.

Comment: I'm thinking there's a language barrier issue happening here.  I'd suggest filing it as a bug with Facebook to see what their devs say.

Comment: I posted the same message in Facebook Developers Group without answer.